# How to use efficiently receive clause in erlang gen_server to resolve timeout error?

Tags: erlang, gen-server

Sometimes my loop returns ok because of timeout how to write this code in proper way. When there is a timeout it just returns ok but not my actual value that I am assuming. In handle call I am calling a function loop() in the loop() function i am receiving a message with receive clause. Now I am sending this data to my database using loop2 function returns response from database whether data has been successfully saved or not and giving response back to loop(). But if there is a timeout my loop function returns ok but not actual value.

```erlang
% @Author: ZEESHAN AHMAD
% @Date:   2020-12-22 05:06:12
% @Last Modified by:   ZEESHAN AHMAD
% @Last Modified time: 2021-01-10 04:42:59


-module(getAccDataCons).

-behaviour(gen_server).

-include_lib("deps/amqp_client/include/amqp_client.hrl").

-export([start_link/0, stop/0]).
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, code_change/3,
         terminate/2]).
-export([get_account/0]).

start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

stop() ->
    gen_server:cast(?MODULE, stop).

get_account() ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {get_account}).

init(_Args) ->
    {ok, Connection} = amqp_connection:start(#amqp_params_network{host = "localhost"}),
    {ok, Channel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(Connection),
    {ok, Channel}.

handle_call({get_account}, _From, State) ->
    amqp_channel:call(State, #'exchange.declare'{exchange = <<"get">>, type = <<"topic">>}),
    amqp_channel:call(State, #'queue.declare'{queue = <<"get_account">>}),
    Binding =
        #'queue.bind'{exchange = <<"get">>,
                      routing_key = <<"get.account">>,
                      queue = <<"get_account">>},
    #'queue.bind_ok'{} = amqp_channel:call(State, Binding),
    io:format(" [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C~n"),
    amqp_channel:call(State,#'basic.consume'{queue = <<"get_account">>, no_ack = true}),
    Returned =loop(),
    io:format("~nReti=~p",[Returned]),
    {reply, Returned, State};
    

handle_call(Message, _From, State) ->
    io:format("received other handle_call message: ~p~n", [Message]),
    {reply, ok, State}.

handle_cast(stop, State) ->
    {stop, normal, State};
handle_cast(Message, State) ->
    io:format("received other handle_cast call : ~p~n", [Message]),
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(Message, State) ->
    io:format("received handle_info message : ~p~n", [Message]),
    {noreply, State}.

code_change(_OldVer, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

terminate(Reason, _State) ->
    io:format("server is terminating with reason :~p~n", [Reason]).


    loop()->
        receive
         #'basic.consume_ok'{} -> ok
        end,
       receive
            {#'basic.deliver'{}, Msg} ->
                #amqp_msg{payload = Payload} = Msg,
                Value=loop2(Payload),
        Value
    after 2000->
    io:format("Server timeout")
    end.


  loop2(Payload)->
            Result = jiffy:decode(Payload),
            {[{<<"account_id">>, AccountId}]} = Result,
            Doc = {[{<<"account_id">>, AccountId}]},
            getAccDataDb:create_AccountId_view(),
            Returned=case getAccDataDb:getAccountNameDetails(Doc) of
                success ->
                    Respo = getAccDataDb:getAccountNameDetails1(Doc),
                     Respo;
                details_not_matched ->
                    user_not_exist
            end,
            Returned.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is too long for an edit, I put it in a new answer.***

The reason why you receive `ok` when a timeout occurs is in the `loop()` code. In the second receive block, after 2000 ms, you return
immediately after the `io:format/1` statement.

`io:format` returns `ok` and it is what you get in the Returned variable. You should change this code with

```
loop()->
    ok = receive
        #'basic.consume_ok'{} -> ok
    end,
    receive
        {#'basic.deliver'{}, #amqp_msg{payload = Payload}} -> {ok,loop2(Payload)}
    after 2000 ->
        io:format("Server timeout"),
        {error,timeout}
    end.
```

With this code your client will receive either `{ok,Value}`, either `{error,timeout}` and will be able to react accordingly.

But there are still issues with this version:
- the 2 seconds timeout is maybe too short and you are missing valid answer
- as you are using pattern matching in the receive blocks and do not check the result of each `amqp_channel:call` there are many different problems that could occur and appear as a timeout

First lets have a look at the timeout. It is possible that the 4 calls to `amqp_channel` really need more than 2 seconds in total to complete successfully. The simple solution is to increase your timeout, changing `after 2000` to `after 3000` or more.
But then you will have 2 issues:

- Your gen_server is blocked during all this time, and if it is not dedicated to a single client, it will be unavailable to
  serve any other request while it is waiting for the answer.
- If you need to increase the timeout above 5 second, you will hit another timeout, managed internally by the gen_server: a request must be answered in less than 5 seconds.

The gen_server offers some interface functions to solve this kind of problem: 'send_request', 'wait_response' and reply. Here is a basic
gen_server which can handle 3 kind of requests:

- stop ... to stop the server, useful to update the code.
- {blocking,Time,Value} the server will sleep during Time ms end then return Value. This simulates your case, and you can tweak how
  long it takes to get an answer.
- {non_blocking,Time,Value} the server will delegate the job to another process and return immediately without answer (therefore
  it is available for another request). the new process will sleep during Time ms end then return Value using gen_server:reply.

The server module implements several user interfaces:

- the standard start(), stop()
- blocking(Time,Value) to call the server with the request {blocking,Time,Value} using gen_server:call
- blocking_catch(Time,Value) same as the previous one, but catching the result of gen_server:call to show the hidden timeout
- non_blocking(Time,Value,Wait) to call the server with the request {non_blocking,Time,Value} using gen_server:send_request and waiting for the answer for Wait ms maximum

Finally it includes 2 test functions

- test([Type,Time,Value,OptionalWait]) it spawns a process which will send a reqest of type with the corresponding parameters. The answer is sent back to the calling process. The answer can be retreive with flush() in the shell.
- parallel_test ([Type,Time,NbRequests,OptionalWait]) it calls NbRequests times test with the corresponding parameters. It collects all
  the answers and print them using the local function collect(NbRequests,Timeout).

Code below

```
-module (server_test).

-behaviour(gen_server).

%% API
-export([start/0,stop/0,blocking/2,blocking_catch/2,non_blocking/3,test/1,parallel_test/1]).


%% gen_server callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
         terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE). 

%%%===================================================================
%%% API
%%%===================================================================
start() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [], []).

stop() ->
    gen_server:cast(?SERVER, stop).

blocking(Time,Value) ->
    gen_server:call(?SERVER, {blocking,Time,Value}).

blocking_catch(Time,Value) ->
    catch {ok,gen_server:call(?SERVER, {blocking,Time,Value})}.

non_blocking(Time,Value,Wait) ->
    ReqId = gen_server:send_request(?SERVER,{non_blocking,Time,Value}),
    gen_server:wait_response(ReqId,Wait).

test([Type,Time,Value]) -> test([Type,Time,Value,5000]);
test([Type,Time,Value,Wait]) ->
    Start = erlang:monotonic_time(),
    From = self(),
    F = fun() -> 
        R = case Type of 
            non_blocking -> ?MODULE:Type(Time,Value,Wait);
            _ -> ?MODULE:Type(Time,Value)
        end,
        From ! {request,Type,Time,Value,got_answer,R,after_microsec,erlang:monotonic_time() - Start} 
    end,
    spawn(F).

parallel_test([Type,Time,NbRequests]) -> parallel_test([Type,Time,NbRequests,5000]);
parallel_test([Type,Time,NbRequests,Wait]) ->
    case Type of
        non_blocking -> [server_test:test([Type,Time,X,Wait]) || X <- lists:seq(1,NbRequests)];
        _ -> [server_test:test([Type,Time,X]) || X <- lists:seq(1,NbRequests)]
    end,
    collect_answers(NbRequests,Time + 1000).


%%%===================================================================
%%% gen_server callbacks
%%%===================================================================
init([]) ->
    {ok, #{}}.

handle_call({blocking,Time,Value}, _From, State) ->
    timer:sleep(Time),
    Reply = {ok,Value},
    {reply, Reply, State};
handle_call({non_blocking,Time,Value}, From, State) ->
    F = fun() ->
        do_answer(From,Time,Value)
    end,
    spawn(F),
    {noreply, State};
handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    Reply = ok,
    {reply, Reply, State}.

handle_cast(stop, State) ->
    {stop,stopped, State};
handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    io:format("changing code replacing version ~p~n",[OldVsn]),
    {ok, State}.

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================

do_answer(From,Time,Value) ->
    timer:sleep(Time),
    gen_server:reply(From, Value).

collect_answers(0,_Timeout) ->
    got_all_answers;
collect_answers(NbRequests,Timeout) ->
    receive 
        A -> io:format("~p~n",[A]),
            collect_answers(NbRequests - 1, Timeout)
    after Timeout ->
        missing_answers
    end.
```

Session in the shell:

```
44> c(server_test).                                    
{ok,server_test}
45> server_test:start().                               
{ok,<0.338.0>}
46> server_test:parallel_test([blocking,200,3]).
{request,blocking,200,1,got_answer,{ok,1},after_microsec,207872}
{request,blocking,200,2,got_answer,{ok,2},after_microsec,415743}
{request,blocking,200,3,got_answer,{ok,3},after_microsec,623615}
got_all_answers
47> % 3 blocking requests in parallel, each lasting 200ms, they are executed in sequence but no timemout is reached
47> % All the clients get their answers
47> server_test:parallel_test([blocking,2000,3]).                                                                                                       
{request,blocking,2000,1,got_answer,{ok,1},after_microsec,2063358}
{request,blocking,2000,2,got_answer,{ok,2},after_microsec,4127740}
missing_answers
48> % 3 blocking requests in parallel, each lasting 2000ms, they are executed in sequence and the last answer exceeds the gen_server timeout.       
48> % The client for this request don't receive answer. The client should also manage its own timeout to handle this case
48> server_test:parallel_test([blocking_catch,2000,3]).                                                                                             
{request,blocking_catch,2000,1,got_answer,{ok,1},after_microsec,2063358}
{request,blocking_catch,2000,2,got_answer,{ok,2},after_microsec,4127740}
{request,blocking_catch,2000,3,got_answer,
         {'EXIT',{timeout,{gen_server,call,[server_test,{blocking,2000,3}]}}},
         after_microsec,5135355}
got_all_answers
49> % same thing but catching the exception. After 5 seconds the gen_server call throws a timeout exception.
49> % The information can be forwarded to the client
49> server_test:parallel_test([non_blocking,200,3]).                                                       
{request,non_blocking,200,1,got_answer,{reply,1},after_microsec,207872}
{request,non_blocking,200,2,got_answer,{reply,2},after_microsec,207872}
{request,non_blocking,200,3,got_answer,{reply,3},after_microsec,207872}
got_all_answers
50> % using non blocking mechanism, we can see that all the requests were managed in parallel 
50> server_test:parallel_test([non_blocking,5100,3]).                                        
{request,non_blocking,5100,1,got_answer,timeout,after_microsec,5136379}
{request,non_blocking,5100,2,got_answer,timeout,after_microsec,5136379}
{request,non_blocking,5100,3,got_answer,timeout,after_microsec,5136379}
got_all_answers
51> % if we increase the answer delay above 5000ms, all requests fail in default timeout
51> server_test:parallel_test([non_blocking,5100,3,6000]).                              
{request,non_blocking,5100,1,got_answer,{reply,1},after_microsec,5231611}
{request,non_blocking,5100,2,got_answer,{reply,2},after_microsec,5231611}
{request,non_blocking,5100,3,got_answer,{reply,3},after_microsec,5231611}
got_all_answers
52> % but thanks to the send_request/wait_response/reply interfaces, the client can adjust the timeout to an accurate value
52> % for each request
```

The next reason why the request could not complete is that one of the amqp_channel:call fails. Depending on what you want to do, there are several
possibilities from doing nothing, let crash, catch the exception or manage all cases. the next proposal uses a global catch

```
handle_call({get_account,Timeout}, From, State) ->
    F = fun() ->
        do_get_account(From,State,Timeout)
    end,
    spawn(F), % delegate the job to another process and free the server
    {noreply, State}; % I don't see any change of State in your code, this should be enough

...

do_get_account(From,State,Timeout) ->
    % this block of code asserts all positive return values from amqp_channel calls. it will catch any error
    % and return it as {error,...}. If everything goes well it return {ok,Answer}
    Reply = try
        ok = amqp_channel:call(State, #'exchange.declare'{exchange = <<"get">>, type = <<"topic">>}),
        ok = amqp_channel:call(State, #'queue.declare'{queue = <<"get_account">>}),
        Binding = #'queue.bind'{exchange = <<"get">>,
                                routing_key = <<"get.account">>,
                                queue = <<"get_account">>},
        #'queue.bind_ok'{} = amqp_channel:call(State, Binding),
        ok = amqp_channel:call(State,#'basic.consume'{queue = <<"get_account">>, no_ack = true}),
        {ok,wait_account_reply(Timeout)}
    catch
        Class:Exception -> {error,Class,Exception}
    end,
    gen_server:reply(From, Reply).

wait_account_reply(Timeout) ->
    receive
    % #'basic.consume_ok'{} -> ok % you do not handle this message, ignore it since it will be garbaged when the process die
        {#'basic.deliver'{}, #amqp_msg{payload = Payload}} -> extract_account(Payload)
    after Timeout->
       server_timeout
    end.


extract_account(Payload)->
        {[{<<"account_id">>, AccountId}]} = jiffy:decode(Payload),
        Doc = {[{<<"account_id">>, AccountId}]},
        getAccDataDb:create_AccountId_view(), % What is the effect of this function, what is the return value?
        case getAccDataDb:getAccountNameDetails(Doc) of
            success ->
                getAccDataDb:getAccountNameDetails1(Doc);
            details_not_matched ->
                user_not_exist
        end.
```

And the client should looks like:

```
get_account() ->
    ReqId = gen_server:send_request(server_name,{get_account,2000}),
    gen_server:wait_response(ReqId,2200).
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the `loop` and `loop2` code, it is hard to give an answer, and if the timeout is detected by one of these 2 functions, you must first change their behavior to avoid any timeout, or increase it to a value that works. If a timeout is necessary, then ensure that the return value is explicit wet it occurs, for example `{error,RequestRef,timeout}` rather than `ok`.

Nevertheless the `gen_server` should not wait too long for an answer, you can modify your code doing:

Instead of using `gen_server:call(ServerRef,Request)` in the client process, you could use:

```
RequestId = send_request(ServerRef, Request),
Result = wait_response(RequestId, Timeout),
```

And remove the timeout in `loop` and/or `loop2`. Doing this you can control the timeout on the client side, you can even set it to infinity (not a good idea!).

Or you can split your function in two parts

```
gen_server:cast(ServerRef,{Request,RequestRef}), 
% this will not wait for any answer, RequestRef is a tag to identify later 
% if the request was fulfilled, you can use make_ref() to generate it
```

and later, or in another client process (this need to pass at least the `RequestRef` to this process) Check the result for request:

```
Answer = gen_server:call(ServerRef,{get_answer,RequestRef}),
case Answer of
    no_reply -> ... % no answer yet
    {ok,Reply} -> ... % handle the answer
end,
```

finally you must modify the loop code to handle the `RequestRef`, send back a message (using again `gen_server:cast`) to the server with the result and the `RequestRef`, and store this result in the server state.

I don't think this second solution is valuable since it is more or less the same than the first one, but hand made, and it let you to manage  many error cases (such as client death) that could end into a kind of memory leak.

Comment: i have  updated my code with loop() and loop2()

Comment: @Coderops see my new response